# 301 Redirect Remove first directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have a couple of urls I would like to remove the entire directoy section from a url. What would the htaccess 301 redirect be? Can someone assist.

Eg.

```
https://example.com/first-lastname-word1-word2/biography/firstnamelastname
https://example.com/first-lastname-word1-word2/activity/firstnamelastname
https://example.com/first-lastname-word1-word2/announcements/firstnamelastname
https://example.com/first-lastname-word1-word2/wall/firstnamelastname
```

To be https://example.com/activity/firstnamelastname
https://example.com/biography/firstnamelastname etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mod_rewrite` keep this rule **very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(memorial-photos|videos|images|category)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+/[^.]+)$ /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to do the trick. I get redirect to just the subdomain and no css files load.

Comment: Okay. This seems to do the trick however it conflicts with other urls that i have such as https://example/videos/video/myvideo.html. It makes it https://example.com/video/myvideo.html. How can I opt out of certain directories I can define.

Comment: It doesnt work for the same reason i mentioned above. I would like it so doesnt have the effect for certain directories such as videos,

Comment: check updated code to skip some directories from this rewrite

Comment: OKay the code does work however i have some urls which are longer and unfortunately would not work with the rules. Eg. https://example.com/memorial-photos/category/3064/tylernickelson would show as https://example.com/3064/tylernickelson even if i tell it to skip /memorial-photos/

Comment: There is no way to stop that since above rule will redirect twice. First `/memorial-photos/category/3064/tylernickelson` to `/category/3064/tylernickelson` and then `/category/3064/tylernickelson` to `/3064/tylernickelson` . May be a fix will be to replace first `RewritCond` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(videos|images|category)/ [NC]`

Comment: The way the rule is make is stay as /category/3064/tylernickelson without the memorial-photos

Comment: Didn't undertake your comment. You can use my suggested rewrite condition in previous Comment.

Comment: Well Id like it to skip memorial-photos, right now its removing memorial photos still so the pages till dont render but leaving category. Would this work? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(videos|images|memorial-photos/category)/ [NC]   ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77656/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ivan-vias).